# Node.js/Postgres - Server not accepting JSON

Tags: node.js, json, postgresql

I'm learning how to use the PERN stack and I am currently setting up my backend CRUD routes. I have initiated a Node.js server and Postgres database, but for some reason, my server won't write the JSON that I pass it to the database.

My Node.js code looks like this:

```
app.post("/todos", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { description } = req.body;
    const newTodo = await pool.query("INSERT INTO todo (description) VALUES($1) RETURNING *", [description]);

    res.json(newTodo.rows[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```

I pass the following JSON to the server via Insomnia:

```
{
"description":"Some new task"
}
```

Insomnia then gives me the following JSON back:

```
{
  "todo_id": 14,
  "description": null
}
```

Upon further inspection, Insomnia gives me back the following details:

```
* Preparing request to http://localhost:5000/todos/
* Using libcurl/7.69.1 OpenSSL/1.1.1g zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 libidn2/2.1.1 libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.40.0
* Current time is 2020-08-12T02:32:19.473Z
* Disable timeout
* Enable automatic URL encoding
* Enable SSL validation
* Enable cookie sending with jar of 6 cookies
* Connection 20 seems to be dead!
* Closing connection 20
*   Trying ::1:5000...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 5000 (#21)

> POST /todos/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: insomnia/2020.2.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 45

| {
|   "description": "I need to clean my room"
| }

* upload completely sent off: 45 out of 45 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 33
< ETag: W/"21-35ITUmxJ2Do0aLZuKgJ4ee+3Kto"
< Date: Wed, 12 Aug 2020 02:32:19 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive


* Received 33 B chunk
* Connection #21 to host localhost left intact
```

If anyone has any insight as to where my code is wrong in regard to my routes, it would be of great assistance.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using body-parser middleware? If not please use that one.

Comment: Thank you for your help — I'm using CORS and Express as my middleware.